# Experience Analytics Tracker not being created

Tags: xdb, xconnect, experience-analytics

When viewing chrome dev tools, I can see that the Experience Analytics Tracking cookie (SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE) is not present.

We have made sure that the Analytics.Tracking is set to true, Analytics.Tracking.Enabled is set to true, the VisitorIdentification extension method is set and also that the Analytics.CookieDomain is set correctly.

When viewing the logs, we see the following error:

```
500232 08:57:50 ERROR Cannot create tracker.
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(XmlNode processorNode)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetProcessorObject(XmlNode processorNode)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureSessionContextPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Run>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Monitor>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.EnsureSessionContext()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateTracker.GetTracker.Process(CreateTrackerArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Initialize()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.TypeInitializationException
Message: The type initializer for 'Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.KnownDataDictionaries' threw an exception.
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureDevice..ctor()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.MissingMethodException
Message: Method not found: 'Void Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsNotNull(System.Object, System.String, System.String)'.
Source: Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.DataAdapterProviderCollection.Add(ProviderBase provider)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetProviders[TProvider,TCollection](List`1 nodes)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetProviders[TProvider,TCollection](String rootPath, TProvider& defaultProvider)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.ReadProviders()
   at Sitecore.Configuration.ProviderHelper`2.get_Provider()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Pipelines.InitializeKnownDataDictionaries.InitializeDeviceDataDictionaryProcessor.Process(InitializeKnownDataDictionariesArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Pipelines.InitializeKnownDataDictionaries.InitializeKnownDataDictionariesPipeline.Run(InitializeKnownDataDictionariesArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.KnownDataDictionaries..cctor()
```

Has anyone else experienced this or know what the issue might be? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What sitecore version do you use? It seems that you have incorrect versions of dlls. Main error is:

```
Message: Method not found: 'Void Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsNotNull(System.Object, System.String, System.String)'.
Source: Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess
```

Make sure that this method exist in your version of Sitecore.Kernel.dll

```
/// <summary>Asserts that the specified value is not null.</summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="format">The format.</param>
    /// <param name="arg1">The arg1.</param>
    [AssertionMethod]
    [StringFormatMethod("format")]
    public static void IsNotNull([AssertionCondition(AssertionConditionType.IS_NOT_NULL)] object value, string format, string arg1);
```

Comment: After decompiling the Sitecore.Kernel.dll file it does not appear to be there. The Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess version appears to be 11.18.0.0 whereas the Sitecore.Kernel version is 11.1.0.0.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by adding in the Sitecore.Analytics and Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess DLLs that are included within the base Sitecore installation. Thanks for your help!